# How to get rid of a workflow with an invalid name prefix in Alfresco 4.2?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have an issue where it is not possible for some users to access their tasks.

I've narrowed it down to an errant namespace (due to an earlier development) how can I list all task regarding this workflow and delete them.

Deleting all workflows via the workflow console (attempting to anyway) in order to get rid of these errant affected tasks fails along with pretty much every command designed to return information regarding all workflows.

I was hoping to find the tasks through the Share administration console but so far I haven't succeeded.

Any insight as to how I may be able to bypass this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the workflow-console from alfresco, here is a link to the [wiki](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Workflow_Console)

There are ways to display all workflows even the old deployed ones.
You can do show tasks (path) but you'll get mixed results (old & new).
So just end those tasks and create new ones.

There is no way to 'transfer' tasks from an old def to a new definition.

Comment: I tried this already. I even tried deleting all workflows,but when I do I get a : "org.alfresco.service.namespace.NamespaceException: Namespace prefix wfga is not mapped to a namespace URI". Could it be possible to search for all nodes containing this wfga prefix and remove them from the system?

Comment: And what is wfga? is that an old model you had? If so, just put it back and restart the server and do the same.

Comment: I figured to do this at first, but I didn't have the old models modifications. Based on the new one, I just created a psuedo model which allowed me to finally list everything in the console and wipe everything. Thanks